# Implementing associations with Rspec/Capybara for Ruby with Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, factory-bot

I have a model that has a method like the following:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    MAX_LINES = 100
    MAX_POSTS = 5

    def self.can_post?(user)
      user.posts.count( :conditions => ["lines >= ?", MAX_LINES] ) < MAX_POSTS
    end
end
```

user has_many posts and posts belongs_to user.  I want to build tests for posts_exceeding_max_lines?. I'm following the [FactoryGirl readme](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) to create a user and post factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  # post factory with a `belongs_to` association for the user
  factory :post do
    title "Through the Looking Glass"
    user
  end

  # user factory without associated posts
  factory :user do
    name "John Doe"

    # user_with_posts will create post data after the user has been created
    factory :user_with_posts do
      # posts_count is declared as an ignored attribute and available in
      # attributes on the factory, as well as the callback via the evaluator
      ignore do
        posts_count 5
      end

      # the after(:create) yields two values; the user instance itself and the
      # evaluator, which stores all values from the factory, including ignored
      # attributes; `create_list`'s second argument is the number of records
      # to create and we make sure the user is associated properly to the post
      after(:create) do |user, evaluator|
        FactoryGirl.create_list(:post, evaluator.posts_count, user: user)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In my test, I create the user using:

```
new_posts_count = 5
@user = FactoryGirl.create(:user_with_posts, posts_count: new_posts_count)
```

However, when I try to print out how many posts I have (with require 'pp'):

```
pp @user.posts.count
```

I get 0, no matter what my setting of new_posts_count. How can I change my setup so that I can get a count of 5 posts?

Comment: Look at `log/test.log`. Does it show that the posts are actually being created?

Answer (score 0):

- shouldn't this method be defined on the User?
- what does all this have to do with the factory?
- use an optional parameter instead of a constant

user

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def posts_exceeding_max_lines?(max_lines = 100, max_posts = 5)
    posts.count(:conditions => ["lines >= ?", max_lines] ) < max_posts
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm given that the method is defined in Post. FactoryGirl create stubs I can use for testing the Posts controller. Perhaps I should just relocate the test to the Post model and avoid the need for a factory.